# routing between 2 express apps in same node process

Tags: node.js, express

In my app, which uses express, I have a third-party node.js app that uses http rather than express, and handles it's routes by doing this (shudder)

```
    srv.removeAllListeners("request");

    srv.on("request", function(req, res) { 
      /* do stuff */
    });
```

now, in my app I want to intercept one of the routes (/foo) but it doesn't seem to work because removeAllListeners() clobbers it.

if I remove the removeAllListeners(), then my app.get('/foo',() {})  does fire, but so does the srv.on('request') leading to all sorts of nasty errors

I thought I could get round it by creating two http servers - one for my app and one for the third party app, and configure the thirdparty app to listen on a private port. the plan was to put all of the "intercept" hooks into my app, and if there is no match, to pass on the request to the third party http server

I would rather not have to start 2 node processes to deal with this.

So, to the question:

Is it possible to route a request from one node http server to another without issuing a redirect to the client ?

```
    var express = require('express'),
    myApp = express(),
    myServer = http.createServer(myApp),
    tpServer = require('thirdparty')({port:1234}); // returns a node httpServer

    myApp.get('/foo ... 
    myApp.get('/bar ...

    myApp.get('*', (req,res,next) => {
      /* do something here to pass request to tpServer */
    })
```

thanks